# How do Koreans distinguish 연패(連覇) and 연패(連敗)?

Tags: vocabulary

According to the Naver Korean dictionary, [연패(連覇)](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=27009700) means “to be the champion in a row” and [연패(連敗)](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=27009600) means “to lose in a row”. So they are absolutely identical in appearance but have completely opposite meanings. Are there any ways like in pronunciation or context to tell which meaning the following sentence has?

> 우리 팀은 이 대회에서 3**연패**를 기록했다. 
>   (A) We **lost three times in a row** in this competition. 
>   (B) We **were the champions three times in a row** in this competition.

For example, 연전연패 must mean “to lose continuously”.

Comment: **3연패를 기록했다** is it common to *officially record* X losses in a row? My impression is that X-in-a-row is usually recorded for a winning side against a losing side, or a winning streak in a season/tournament. I'd be inclined to choose (B).

Comment: As a native, it was a same problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. They are pronounced exactly the same. Don't they usually insert hanja if the context doesn't make it clear?

It's mentioned in this google book
https://books.google.com/books?id=W7DNCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%EC%97%B0%ED%8C%A8(%E9%80%A3%E6%95%97)&source=bl&ots=7H8oZI51pY&sig=ef_fWv1uIwrsDjJotFrHSUSiFAA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjguPbFsJXbAhXBjVkKHSCfC20Q6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=%EC%97%B0%ED%8C%A8(%E9%80%A3%E6%95%97)&f=false

a korean person asked the same thing
http://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do;front=1230290FF3E8B3AC3CEF6E4DC8F0D3DA?mn_id=61&qna_seq=100761&pageIndex=1

Answer (score 0):

Not always,

The 연패(losing streak) is often used in 'games'

ex) match35, match 36, match 37..

The 연패(champion in a row) is often used in 'competitions'.

ex) premierleague , champions league ...

Because of the difficulty of classification, 
We write 연승 instead of 연패(champion in a row)